# YEAR cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

In JAVA,

```
Calendar Target_Date = Calendar.getInstance();
Target_Date.set(YEAR,Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("date").split("-")[0]));
```

gives error that `YEAR cannot be resolved to a variable`. Am I not using `set()` correctly? I want to change `Target_Date`'s year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YEAR` is static and you should use it as `Calendar.YEAR` unless you have a static import.